# Intuition behind using a two pointers approach

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I am solving a question on [LeetCode.com](https://www.leetcode.com):

> A string S of lowercase English letters is given. We want to partition this string into as many parts as possible so that each letter appears in at most one part, and return a list of integers representing the size of these parts. 
> For the input: "ababcbacadefegdehijhklij" the output is: [9,7,8]

A [highly upvoted solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-labels/discuss/113259/Java-2-pass-O(n)-time-O(1)-space-extending-end-pointer-solution) is as below:

```java
public List<Integer> partitionLabels(String S) {
    if(S == null || S.length() == 0){
        return null;
    }
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] map = new int[26];  // record the last index of the each char

    for(int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++){
        map[S.charAt(i)-'a'] = i;
    }
    // record the end index of the current sub string
    int last = 0;
    int start = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++){
        last = Math.max(last, map[S.charAt(i)-'a']);
        if(last == i){
            list.add(last - start + 1);
            start = last + 1;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

I understand what we are doing in the first `for` loop (we just store the index of the last occurrence of a character), but I am not too sure about the second one:

a. Why do we calculate the `max()` and compare `last==i`?
b. How does it help us achieve what we seek - in the above example, when we encounter `a` at position `8` (0-indexed), what guarantees that we won't encounter, say `b`, at a position greater than `8`?  Because, if we do, then considering `8` as the end position of our substring is incorrect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we encounter a character `S[i]` we may cut the string only after it's last occurence, hence `map[S.charAt(i)-'a']`. We maximize the value in `last` because we need to ensure that all the processed characters will have their last occurence in the prefix, so we look at the rightmost of such indices, hence the `max`. If we encounter a character `S[i]` such that `i` is it's last occurrence and all characters before have their last occurrences before `i`, we may add the substring `start..i` to the result, and set `start = i + 1` for the next substring.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more with respect to question's part (b)?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela According to your example, let's assume `S[i] == 'a'`. If we met `b` before, either it's last position was before `i`, so `map['b'] < i <= last`, or it is in the rest of the string, so `i < map['b'] <= last`. Note that `i == last` may be true only in the first case, and the same holds for every character in the prefix `0..i`. In other words, if a character that we met before `i`-th position is also found after it, `last` will be greater than `i`, since `last` is equal or greater than the last position of every character we encountered.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is this. Whenever the last occurrence of a particular character matches the current index, it means that this particular character appears only in this part.

To understand this better, just do this.

```
int last = 0;
int start = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++){
   last = Math.max(last, map[S.charAt(i)-'a']);
   System.out.println(last+" "+i);
   if(last == i){
      list.add(last - start + 1);
      start = last + 1;
   }
}
```

Take your example string `"ababcbacadefegdehijhklij"`.

Now, the output would be

```
8 0
8 1
8 2
8 3
8 4
8 5
8 6
8 7
8 8
14 9
15 10
15 11
15 12
15 13
15 14
15 15
19 16
22 17
23 18
23 19
23 20
23 21
23 22
23 23
```

The last occurrence of `a` is at the 8th position. Now we are at 0th position. Increment i. So, the till we get to 8th position, we cant be sure that each part contains at most 1 character. Suppose the next character is `b` and it occurs finally in 10th position, then we need to confirm till 10th position.

```
if(last == i){

}
```

The above `if` just confirms that the part is over and we can start a new part from the next index. Before doing this, we are adding the length of the current part to the output.

Comment: Well, I get _this_; what I don't get is this - when we encounter `a` at position `8` (0-indexed), what guarantees that we won't encounter, say `b`, at a position greater than `8`?  Because, if we do, then considering `8` as the end position of our substring is incorrect.

Comment: That is why `last = max(last,map[S.charAt(i)-'a'])`  is used. See, let's say you get such a `b` at 10th position, then last would be increased to 10. Meaning the part cannot end before 10. I hope you got it. Let me know if you haven't.

Comment: Then how does it prevent, say `e`, from being included in the calculation of `max()`?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela When `(last == i)`, it means that the current part is over. Now, when you get `e`, you take the last occurrence. Unless you move to the last occurrence you cant be sure that the part has at most 1 character. Still not clear?